# How to query Github enterprise using REST

Tags: github, github-api, github-enterprise, github-api-v3

I would like to know how do we connect to enterprise version of github and access multiple data like , organization settings, users, repositories etc.,

I can find in google that we can access open github details using endpoint

```
https://api.github.com/
```

how about access my Enterprise version ? 
considering enterprise name "test".
I can login into it through web using
`"https://github.com/enterprises/test/people"`

Can you please help me in pointing a REST guide or example to access data please.

I tried using `https://api.github.com/enterprises/test` but no luck

kindly help

Comment: Is this related to GitHub Enterprise Server (hosted on your own company's infrastructure on its own domain) or are you still using GitHub.com to access this data?

Comment: Hi Brendan, I have found the solution when raised a support with Github team. Thank you very much for your consideration

Comment: @AbhishekRenduchintala Make sure to document below (as an answer here on Stack Overflow) in details that solution when you have it. I don't want another "DenverCoder9" (https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to pass an valid access token

To query Users :

https://api.github.com/user/orgs

To query members in an organization. were {organization} is the organization name case sensitive

https://api.github.com/orgs/{organization}/members